# Change Hostname Vagrant

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile

I've setup two vagrant VMs of ubuntu - one for slave and one for master.I frequently get confused after logging into the vagrant VM using **vagrant ssh** which machine I'm in. What do I call this green string in the screenshot and how do I change this this for both slave and master machines like ubuntuslave and ubuntumaster?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The string in green is of the format `<username>@<hostname>`.  So in order to differentiate between your two servers, you need to change the hostname, to give you something like `ubuntu@ubuntu-slave`.

To do this, you need to add the [hostname configuration option](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html) to your Vagrantfile:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   config.vm.box = "precise32"
   config.vm.hostname = "ubuntu-slave"
   config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.10"
end
```

This, however, will only update your hostname **after you recreate the VMs**.  If you aren't planning on doing this, you will also need to modify the hostname [within Ubuntu itself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name).

Comment: `vagrant reload` will change your SSH hostname without having to recreate the VMs @Sukumar